# How to implement a SharePoint calculated column inside Canvas app form and have its value changed directly inside the Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, powerapp, powerapps-forms

We have 5 SharePoint fields been displayed inside a Canvas app forum:-

1. Q1 of type currency
2. Q2 of type currency
3. Q3 of type currency
4. Q4 of type currency
5. Percentage of type number

and i want to implement a calculated field named "Total" inside the canvas app forum, as follow:-

```
(Q1 - Q2 - Q3 - Q4) * 100%
```

then inside the canvas app i want to show/hide some fields based on this "Total" value range. now if i implemented the  "Total" field as calculated column inside share Point list, and the user modify the above 5 fields, the calculated column value will not get affected unless we submit the form.. so how i can dynamically set& get the value of the calculated column inside the canvas app form ?